# BGMとして自動音声再生、ループを指示したいがJavaScriptで動かない。

Tags: javascript, monaca

monacaで開発しています。

audioだとアンドロイドでサポートしないという事でしたので、
PhoneGap の Media APIを使用してmp3をBGMとして再生したい
と思っています。

・参考にしたサイト
https://blog.e2info.co.jp/2014/06/30/monaca%E3%81%A7iphone%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA/

head内に下記を入れてみましたがエラーで画面すら開かなくなりました。

```
<script> 
 // PhoneGap event handler
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("PhoneGap is ready");
    //音楽再生関数を呼びます
    playAudio();
}

var media = null;
var mediaTimer = null;

//音楽再生関数
function playAudio() {
    var src = 'sound.mp3';
    media = new Media ('/' + src , onSuccess, onError);

    //再生
    media.play({numberOfLoops:"infinite"});

    if (mediaTimer == null) {
        mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
            // 再生位置を返します
            media.getCurrentPosition(
                //成功時のコールバック関数です
                function(position) {
                    if (position > -1) {
                        setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        //端末によっては再生位置が-0.001で止まるので、その場合は再度読み込みます。
                        if(position == -0.001){
                            media.play({numberOfLoops:"infinite"});
                        }
                    }
                },
                //失敗時のコールバック関数です
                function(e) {
                    console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                }
            );
        }, 1000);
    }
}
//成功時
function onSuccess() {
    console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
}
//失敗時
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
    'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

//オーディオ再生位置
function setAudioPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
}
</script>
```

初歩的な質問ですみませんが、ご教授下さい。

Comment: まず、エラーが発生しているならエラーの内容も記述して欲しいです。また、音声ファイルの保存先までのパスは大丈夫でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

再生できるサンプルを取りあえず作成してみました。
音声パスは絶対パスでないと再生出来ないかと思います。
`playAudio('sound.mp3',true);`でループ再生できるかと思います。
`deviceready`時に呼び出して試してみてください。

```
var media = null;       //Mediaオブジェクト
var mediaTimer = null;  //再生位置を逐次取得する為のタイマー

/**
 * 相対パスから絶対パスに変換するためにカレントパスの取得
 **/
function getPath() {
    var str = location.pathname;
    var i = str.lastIndexOf('/');
    return str.substring(0,i+1);
}

/**
 * 再生開始
 **/
function playAudio(audio_src, isLoop) {
    if(typeof isLoop === 'undefined'){isLoop=false;}
    //音声パス, 成功時コールバック, 失敗時コールバック
    media = new Media (getPath() + audio_src , function(){console.log("play start");}, function(error){console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');});

    if(monaca.isIOS){
        //ファイルを再生(オプション値はiOSのみ有効)
        //{numberOfLoops:"infinite"}を引数にするとループ / { playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked:false }マナーモードを有効
        if(isLoop){
            media.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked:false, numberOfLoops:"infinite"});
        }else{
            media.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked:false});
        }

        if(mediaTimer == null){
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                //再生位置
                if(isset(media)){
                    media.getCurrentPosition(
                        function(position) {
                            if(0 > position){
                                //再生位置バグ用リロード
                                if(isLoop){media.play();}
                                else{stopAudio();}
                            }
                        },
                        function(e){
                            console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }else{
        media.play();
        if(mediaTimer == null){
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                //再生位置を取得
                if(isset(media)){
                    media.getCurrentPosition(
                        function(position) {
                            //再生の終了位置にバグがある為対処
                            if(0 > position){
                                if(isLoop){media.play();}
                                else{stopAudio();}
                            }
                        },
                        function(e){
                            console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 遅レスになりましたが、コードありがとうございます。
絶対パスの指定のロジックで、無事に再生できました。